# Accordion in my FAQ Page, Chevron moves horizontally

Tags: css, rotation, accordion

I am building a small online shop using Shopify, and I am getting back into programming/coding after dropping out of my "IT school" in which I had to do more electrical engineering and metalworking than actual programming.

I want to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript to further improve my shop. I built (copied) an accordion style FAQ page. (This one right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJoxQMKV-ew)

It looks really nice and I am really happy with it. However, there is an issue. If the question is multiple lines long (especially on mobile since the screen width is much smaller than Desktop, and the majority of the customers use mobile), the chevron which rotates when the question is opened, moves horizontally, and that doesn't look good at all. I tried searching for solutions but I couldn't find anything. This is my last resort.

Here's a video of my problem: https://gfycat.com/shortripeblackwidowspider

And heres the CSS:

```css
.faq {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.faq .tab-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.faq .tab-label {
  background-color: black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color:white;
}
.faq .tab-label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}
.faq .tab-toggle:checked ~ .tab-label {
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}
.faq .tab-label::after {
  content:'\276F';
  transition: all .4s;
}
.faq .tab-toggle:checked ~ .tab-label::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
.faq .tab-content {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .4s;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.faq .tab-toggle:checked ~ .tab-content
{
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Would be preferable to provide a reproductible example using the code snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `transform-origin` to ensure your element pivots around it's center, add:

```
transform-origin: 0 50%;
```

to your `.faq .tab-label::after` styles.